# Error in R electricShine::electrify() Error: ! Failed to evaluate glue component {arch} Caused by error: ! object 'arch' not found

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, electron, shinyapps

I created a package file using golem. The package build completes without error. However, I am attempting to create an exe file using electricShine::electrify but I get the error:

Finshed: Installing your Shiny package into electricShine framework
Successfully created C:/Dev/Temp/Rtmp6bvPzB/My_App/package.json
Error:
! Failed to evaluate glue component {arch}
Caused by error:
! object 'arch' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

similar to the issue on the [github](https://github.com/chasemc/electricShine/issues/429)

```
buildPath <- tempdir()

Sys.setenv(R_LIBCURL_SSL_REVOKE_BEST_EFFORT=TRUE)

options(timeout=500)

platform <- "win"

electricShine::electrify(app_name = "My_App",
                          short_description = "My demo application",   
                          semantic_version = "1.0.0",
                          build_path = buildPath,
                          mran_date = NULL,
                          cran_like_url = "https://cran.r-project.org",
                          function_name = "run_app",
                          local_package_path = path_to_app,
                          package_install_opts = list(type = "binary", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports")), 
                          run_build = TRUE,
                          nodejs_version = "v20.11.0")
```

```
rlang::last_trace()
```

### <error/rlang_error>
Error:
! Failed to evaluate glue component {arch}
Caused by error:
! object 'arch' not found

Backtrace:
x

1. -electricShine::electrify(...)
2. -electricShine::install_nodejs(...)
   Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 13 hidden frames.

```
version()
```

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          3.2
year           2023
month          10
day            31
svn rev        85441
language       R
version.string R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Eye Holes

I've tried npm install arch